# Iterate in hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap and want to get the key and value by iterating. I keep adding entries to oneList and oneMap multiple times. I'm getting only the first "string variable" multiple times.

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> oneMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Object>>();
List<Object> oneList = new LinkedList<Object>();

oneList.add("one");
oneList.add(FieldType);

oneMap.put("1", oneList);

//iterating through the map
for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<Object>> entry : oneMap.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println("Compare Key :: " +entry.getKey());
     oneList = entry.getValue();
     String oneSrvFld = (String) oneList.get(0);
     System.out.println("one srvFld :: " +oneSrvFld);
}
```

Comment: Because that's what your code does. It's retrieving the first value.

Comment: `List<Object>`. `Generics` *used* . But for *what?*?

Comment: You only have one Map entry

Comment: oneList.get(0); <- Do you see the issue here?

Comment: Your code wont do what you expected (It can't read your mind). It will do what you ask to do by coding.

Comment: @TheLostMind - to silence irritating compiler warnings, I'd imagine.

Comment: @Jules - I know.. But quite pointless considering the fact that it serves no purpose.. Unless you consider *silencing the compiler* as a purpose. :)

Comment: Thanks Folks, I gave an example by adding only one entry into the List. I have inserted multiple entries but while fetching from Map was getting the same value while iterating. The reason being i was not clearing the List while adding an entry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    Map<Integer, List<Object>> oneMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Object>>();
    List<Object> oneList = new LinkedList<Object>();

    oneList.add("one");
    oneList.add("FieldType");

    oneMap.put(1, oneList);

    //iterating through the map
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<Object>> entry : oneMap.entrySet()) {
         System.out.println("Compare Key :: " +entry.getKey());
         oneList = entry.getValue();
         for(int i=0;i<oneList.size();i++){
             System.out.println("one srvFld :: " +oneList.get(i)); 
         }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting   `(String) oneList.get(0);` will get you the first element and remove it from the list. But get(index) returns at the specified position in  the list without removing the element

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting the first string multiple times is because you're only retrieving the first string in the list.  Your code for getting data out of the list is this line:

```
String oneSrvFld = (String) oneList.get(0);
```

This just gets the first item in the list and ignores the rest.  As you only have one list, you therefore only ever see one string.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but possible solutions would include creating a new list for each entry in your map, or iterating over all the entries in the list when you get it out of the map.